# Trigger Google Cloud SQL export within VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-iam

*tl;dr:* Cannot trigger an export with `gcloud sql export sql ...` on VM which always leads into a PERMISSION_DENIED even though I think that I have set all permissions for its Service Account.

---

The whole problem actually sounds relatively simple. I want to trigger an export of my Cloud SQL database in my Google Cloud Compute VM at certain times.

#### What I did so far:

1. Added the `Cloud SQL Admin` (just for the sake of testing) permission to the VMs service account in the IAM section.
2. Created and downloaded the service account key and used `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file cert.json`
3. Ran the following command:

```sh
gcloud sql export sql "${SQL_INSTANCE}" "gs://${BUCKET}/${FILENAME}" -d "${DATABASE}"
```

**(this works without a problem with my own, personal account)**

---

**The command resulted in the following error:**

> ERROR: (gcloud.sql.export.sql) PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

#### What else I tried

I found [this article from Google](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scheduling-cloud-sql-database-exports-using-cloud-scheduler) and used the Compute Service Account instead of creating a Cloud Function Service Account. The result is sadly the same.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have the roles assigned to the service account that you think you have.

You need one of the following roles assigned to the service account:

- roles/owner (**Not recommended**)
- roles/viewer (**Not recommended**)
- roles/cloudsql.admin (Not recommended unless required for other SQL operations)
- roles/cloudsql.editor (Not recommended unless required for other SQL operations)
- roles/cloudsql.viewer (Recommended)

Go to the Google Cloud Console -> Compute Engine.
Click on your VM instance. Scroll down and find the service account assigned to your VM instance. Copy the service account email address.

Run the following command (replace \ with ^ for Windows in the following command and specify your PROJECT ID (not PROJECT NAME) and the service account email address):

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy <PROJECT_ID>  \
--flatten="bindings[].members" \
--format="table(bindings.role)" \
--filter="bindings.members:<COMPUTE_ENGINE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT>"
```

Double-check that the roles you require are present in the output.

To list your projects to obtain the PROJECT ID:

```
gcloud projects list
```

Note: Do not assign permissions directly to the service account. Assign permissions to the project granting the required role to the service account IAM member.

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <PROJECT_ID> \
  --member serviceAccount:<COMPUTE_ENGINE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT> \
  --role roles/cloudsql.viewer
```